# Arrows top and bottom, how to optimalise CSS?

Tags: html, css, optimization, css-shapes

My problem is that I want to display 'arrows' above and below certain sections (which I have given classes of course).

These arrows can be both bottom, top and you can pick left and right for both the bottom and top arrow:[image]

I made a snippet to demonstrate, but wasn't able to insert the SVG properly, so have replaced that code with `background: red;`.

The problem with above code is that it uses a wildcard selector on the classes, so it might interfere. So I would prefer something like `class="arrow arrow-top arrow-left"`. However, that gives a problem when you add two arrows to one section: `class="arrow arrow-top arrow-left arrow-bottom arrow-right"`.

Any suggestions on how to optimise this code?

```css
[class*=arrow]:before, [class*=arrow]:after {
 content: '';
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 50px;
 height: 12vw;
 width: 100%;
 //background-image: url("arrow.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))");
  background-color: red;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}
[class*=arrow-top] {
 padding-top: 50px;
 padding-top: 12vw;
}
[class*=arrow-bottom] {
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 padding-bottom: 12vw;
}

.arrow-top-left:before {
 display: block;
 top: 0;
}

.arrow-top-right:before {
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.arrow-bottom-left:after {
 display: block;
 bottom: 0;
 transform: scaleY(-1);
}
.arrow-bottom-right:after {
 display: block;
 bottom: 0;
 transform: scale(-1, -1);
}

/* unessential code */

section {
  background-color: #EC644B;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
section:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #DCC6E0;
}
p {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="arrow  arrow-top   arrow-bottom-left">
  <p>Een prachtige sectie</p>
</section>
<section class="arrow-top-right  arrow-bottom-right">
  <p>Een prachtige sectie</p>
</section>
<section class="arrow-bottom-right">
  <p>Een prachtige sectie</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague thought about this and came up with this SASS-solution:

```
.u-arrow {

    &-top,
    &-bottom {

        &-right,
        &-left {
            position: relative;


            &:before,
            &:after {
                z-index: 0;
                content: '';
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                height: 50px;
                height: 12vw;
                width: 100%;
                background-size: 100% 100%;
                background-image: url("/dist/images/arrow-white-mobile.svg");

                .u-bg-blue & {
                    background-image: url("/dist/images/arrow-blue-mobile.svg");
                }

                @media (min-width: $screen-sm) {
                    background-image: url("/dist/images/arrow-white.svg");

                    .u-bg-blue & {
                        background-image: url("/dist/images/arrow-blue.svg");
                    }
                }

                @media (min-width: 1200px) {
                    height: 150px;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    &-top {

        &-left,
        &-right {
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-top: 12vw;

            @media (min-width: 1200px) {
                padding-top: 150px;
            }

            &:before {
                display: block;
                top: 0;
            }
        }

        &-right {
            &:before {
                transform: scaleX(-1);
            }
        }
    }

    &-bottom {

        &-left,
        &-right {
            padding-bottom: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 12vw;

            @media (min-width: 1200px) {
                padding-bottom: 150px;
            }

            &:after {
                display: block;
                bottom: 0;
            }
        }

        &-left {
            &:after {
                transform: scaleY(-1);
            }
        }

        &-right {
            &:after {
                transform: scale(-1, -1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider linear-gradient and you can easily achieve this by having two classes for each arrow that you can combine:

```css
.top-arrow,.bottom-arrow {
  margin:5px;
  min-height:200px;
  max-width:400px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  border:1px solid;
}
.top-arrow:before,
.bottom-arrow:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
.top-arrow:before {
  background:
   linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 50%,red 50.5%) top left/20% 50% no-repeat,
   linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,red 50.5%) top right/80% 50.5% no-repeat;
}

.bottom-arrow:after {
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 50%,pink 50.5%) bottom left /80% 50% no-repeat,
   linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,pink 50.5%) bottom right /20% 50.5% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-arrow bottom-arrow">
</div>
<div class="bottom-arrow">
</div>
<div class="top-arrow">
</div>
```

Comment: The linear-gradient isn't possible because there has to be a slight rounding at the edge. And also, the bottom arrow should be able to be shown as both a right and left arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CSS `clip-path`'s to create the shapes you want within you `:before`'s and `:after`'s.

You will get a slick outcome, with solid corners and it will also be very easy to change their shape to your desires.

- [clip-path - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)
- [CanIUse Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)
- [clip-path Generator](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  padding: 30px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EC644B;
  position: relative;
}

section:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #DCC6E0
}

.arrow-top-left,
.arrow-top-right {
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.arrow-top-left:before,
.arrow-top-right:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: blue;
}

.arrow-top-left:before {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(20% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
}

.arrow-top-right:before {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(80% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(80% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
}

.arrow-bottom-left,
.arrow-bottom-right {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.arrow-bottom-left:after,
.arrow-bottom-right:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: green;
}

.arrow-bottom-left:after {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

.arrow-bottom-right:after {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(80% 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(80% 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<section class="arrow-top-left arrow-bottom-right">

</section>
<section class="arrow-bottom-right">

</section>
<section class="arrow-top-right">

</section>
```

Comment: Fine solution, but the problem is not the creating of the corners (because the client wants them to have rounded corners). The main objecte of this question was an optimalisation of already-written code. A colleague fixed it now though, using SASS.

Comment: Ahh, you can still use `clip-path`, I will add the amendment in a min even though its already been fixed.